# Catch clause for endless repeating number

Tags: c#, excel, exception, sql-server-2008-r2

I am loading values from excel in C#, which is then turned into a string which I then want to save in SQL Server 2008 R2. How can I catch or reformat floats like 0.3333333333?

I get the following error: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Can you post the relevant bit of your code pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int number = 1;
float number2 = (float)number;
number2.toString("0.00") //2dp - add more zeros to define the number of dp you want
```